# Jquery Drop Down Box issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm currently having an issue implementing a dropdown menu using Jquery using the .hover option.

The issue is that it sometimes disappears even when you are hovering over the element.

The JSFiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/liamsorsby/dN3Tr/

but if you wish to see the code here it is below:

html

```
<div class="header_links">
        <ul>
            <li class="occasion_title occ">OCCASION
                <div class="occasions occ">
                    <ul class="occ">
                        <li><p>test</p></li>
                        <li><p>test</p></li>
                        <li><p>test</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".occ").hover(
    function(){
        $(".occasions").css("display","inline");
    },
    function(){
        $(".occasions").css("display","none");
    });
```

CSS

```
.header_links{
float:left;
margin-left:12px;
}
.header_links ul{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
.header_links li{
border:1px solid #C09356;
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
width:125px;
font-family:Arial;
position:relative;
color:#000000;
height:35px;
background-color:none;
}
.occasions{
display:none;
position:absolute;
margin-top:23px;
margin-left:-96px;
z-index:3000;
}
.occasions li{
border:1px solid #C09356;
height:25px;
width:110px;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:center;
}
.occasions p{
margin:3px 0 0 0;
padding:0px;
}
```

I have as an alternative tried using mouseover and the mouseleave but had the same issue. Can anyone suggest how to improve this code? Thank you in advance

Comment: It's probably because you're using `$(".occ").hover()` and there are multiple elements in there with the same class. Use `occasion_title` for hover instead which is unique.

Comment: @Krishna i have used the class multiple times to try and get the hover to stay active in IE8 which it currently is not the occasion_title hover does work but not very well on ie8

Comment: check if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of you page..

Comment: i've got <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to target `occasion_title` instead of `occ` to achieve your requirement.

just change this line:

```
$(".occ").hover
```

to this one:

```
$(".occasion_title").hover
```

a working Fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/dN3Tr/2/

Comment: works like a treat on firefox but not on IE8 any suggestions?

Comment: No, don't know why.
please consider to "mark as answer" if it really helped you solving your question. many thanks :)

Comment: i've marked the answer up but it's not completely resolved the issue

Comment: with all my respect, my answer has addressed your question perfectly, the issue of not working on IE8 is another thing, not that your question was asking how to get it to work probably, not asking about an error on IE :)
anyway, it's your decision, and I respect it.

Comment: the dropdown was to far down so it hid itself

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with ditching the jQuery, you could use just CSS to do this:

```
.occasion_title:hover .occasions {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: this also works fine other then with IE 8 any ideas as to why?

Comment: It seems to be working for me in IE8: [link](http://jsbin.com/EvakIdE/1/edit)  I copy/pasted your code into jsbin, since fiddle doesn't get along well with IE8.